# Website goes down if wordpress theme provider's site is down for maintenance

Tags: wordpress

I have installed a paid WordPress theme and deployed it on my IIS server. The website goes down every time the wordpress theme developer's site is down for maintenance.

I am not able to determine which piece of code is hitting their website. Could anyone point me in the right direction and advise regarding steps I should take to remove all dependencies from their website

Comment: Why not ask the developper himself, if you paid for it?

Comment: Well usually it don't happen,if it does then check your service provider

Comment: I think, Theme developer passing values from his website to your website by using plugin like "easy digital downloads"

Comment: It is a paid theme and I have written to the developers. But they always take a while to respond and this is a serious issue. Is there a way I can see what script/plugin may be dependent on third party server?

Comment: Search through all the plugin files for the developer's site's domain.  If that doesn't work, in the database check all wp_options.option_value fields for the domain.  That might point you in the right direction.